# Regex for camel case BEM

Tags: css, regex, sass, stylelint

I need a regex pattern to match camel case BEM classes following this structure:

`BlockName_elementName-modifierName`

I've created this regex to do the job:

`([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)+(\_[a-z0-9]+[A-Z0-9]?[a-z0-9]*)?(\-[a-z0-9]+[A-Z0-9]?[a-z0-9]*)?`

Examples of strings that should match:

```
Block
BlockName
BlockNameLonger
BlockName93

BlockName_element
BlockName_elementName
BlockName_elementNameLonger
BlockName_4elementName

BlockName_elementName-modifier
BlockName_elementName-modifierName
BlockName_elementName-modifierNameLonger
BlockName_elementName-modifier567Name
```

Currently it matches all except the 'longer' strings. I can't work out how to group correctly to match any length of camel case groups. Can anyone help?

See demo here: http://regexr.com/3h0sf

Comment: Your regex appears to be working for me.  Can you include some negative cases?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In the link I posted the strings with `Longer` at the end are being matched as 2 separate things rather than a single match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Original: `([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)+(\_[a-z0-9]+[A-Z0-9]?[a-z0-9]*)?(\-[a-z0-9]+[A-Z0-9]?[a-z0-9]*)?`

Split into groups to understand what each is matching:

- `([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)+` At least 1 group of 1 Uppercase and at least 1 lower/number
- `(\_[a-z0-9]+[A-Z0-9]?[a-z0-9]*)?` Optionally, an underscore followed by some number of lower/number, then optionally one upper, then any amount of lower/number
- `(\-[a-z0-9]+[A-Z0-9]?[a-z0-9]*)?` Same as above, except starting with a dash.

We need to change the 2nd and 3rd to behave like the 1st after a group of lowercase, so we just need to splice it into them:

- `(\_[a-z0-9]+([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*)?` (Change the + to a * because there might not be any uppercase groups)
- `(\-[a-z0-9]+([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*)?`

All together:

```
([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)+(\_[a-z0-9]+([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*)?(\-[a-z0-9]+([A-Z][a-z0-9]+)*)?
```

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant, but this will match `BlockName-modifierNameLonger`; if that's not a valid construction, it can be changed to avoid it.

Comment: Fantastic! It always seems so obvious when someone shows you the way. Thank you. With regards to your comment, since this still follows traditional BEM rules, yes a block can be followed by a modifier so it's fine for it to match that too.